# KnockoutJs filter empties the list after search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am using KnockoutJs to build a search list, the code as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="search" id="search-bar" placeholder="Enter a name" data-bind="value:query,valueUpdate: 'keyup'">
<div id="list" data-bind='template: {foreach: name}'>
    <li data-bind='text $data'></li>
</div>
```

**Part of Js search function:**

```
this.name = ko.observable('');
this.query = ko.observable('');
this.search = function (value) {
    self.name([]);
    for (var x in name) {
        if (name[x].toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
            self.name.push(name[x]);
        }
    }
}

this.query.subscribe(self.search);
```

The data (2-D list) is retrieved from a different URL using $.get and then parsed, I then assigned every first entry (arsed_data[i][0]) of the parsed data as name observable shown in the code.

The list meant to filter the content according to the searchbox entry, and it displays all the names initially, but as soon as I type something in the searchbox, the name list becomes empty, what could be the possible cause and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: What's `self`? Have you set `var self = this;` in code you haven't shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest introducing computed observable (say `self.filteredNames`) that would be dependent on both `self.names` array (it should be `ko.observableArray` indeed) and current value of `self.query`
You can then bind your template to `self.filteredNames` instead of `self.names`
A fragment of View Model definition could look like this:

```
self = this;
/* ... any other code related to VM */
self.names = ko.observableArray([]);    //    it's supposed to be later filled with AJAX requests
//  self.names = ko.observableArray(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']);    //    however you can try with this not to bother with actual data loading
self.query = ko.observable('');
self.filteredNames = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    //    value of this pureComputed observable would be automatically updated each time either self.query or self.names is updated
    return self.names().filter(function(item) { 
        return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.query().toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    });
});
/* ... any other code related to VM */
```

A version of markup that allows to test how it works could look like this:

```
<input type="search" id="search-bar" placeholder="Enter a name" data-bind="value:query,valueUpdate: 'keyup'">
<ul id = "list" data-bind='foreach: filteredNames'>
    <li data-bind=' text: $data'></li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use array methods like `push` and such directly on the observable, you need to make it an [observable *array*](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html), not just an observable. E.g.:

```
this.name = ko.observableArray();
```

not

```
this.name = ko.observable('');
```

Even though you have `self.name([])` later, the observable is still just an observable (whose value is an array), not an observable array.

(I'm assuming you have `var self = this;` somewhere above the code you've shown.)

Also, since it's an array of name**s**, you might want to call it `names` rather than `name`.

---

Side note: If the `name` in `for (var x in name) {` is an array, that's not how you should loop through arrays. See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) for various correct ways to loop through arrays.

---

Side note 2: The `template` binding in your HTML seems suspect. You're providing the HTML right there, not in a separate template. So it should just be `data-bind="foreach: name"`.